# Geth 1.4.10 -- faild enc handshake: EOF

Tags: go-ethereum

Geth suddenly stopped working for me - when I run it on verbosity level 5 I get repeating error messages like the following:

```
dyn dial conn 120.27.122.174:30303 faild enc handshake: EOF
```

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Comment: The "enc" is "encryption". Is the repeating error for the same IP address (i.e. the same peer), or for lots of different IP addresses?

Comment: It repeats this error for many IP addresses, never gets past this issue, keeps repeating the same error.

Comment: what is the result of admin.nodeInfo ? admin.peers?
I think the issue is related to your node IP (library problem or a networking issue)

Comment: what is the result of admin.nodeInfo ? admin.peers?
I think the issue is related to your node IP (library problem or a networking issue)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relates to an old version of Geth, and there are no other reports of similar errors in newer versions. (And it's unlikely that a definitive answer can now be given.)

Answer (score 2):

I would point to a **connectivity issue**. Did you verify that your network has port 30303 open and forwarding to the server where you node is running? Some firewall configurations can prevent UDP traffic from flowing. You can use the static nodes feature or admin.addPeer() on the console to configure connections by hand.

You can run the following to calls using Geth and verify if everything is correct in your network setup

```
> admin.peers
[{
  ID: 'a4de274d3a159e10c2c9a68c326511236381b84c9ec52e72ad732eb0b2b1a2277938f78593cdbe734e6002bf23114d434a085d260514ab336d4acdc312db671b',
  Name: 'Geth/v0.9.14/linux/go1.4.2',
  Caps: 'eth/60',
  RemoteAddress: '5.9.150.40:30301',
  LocalAddress: '192.168.0.28:39219'
}, {
...
```

```
> admin.nodeInfo
{
  Name: 'Geth/v0.9.14/darwin/go1.4.2',
  NodeUrl: 'enode://3414c01c19aa75a34f2dbd2f8d0898dc79d6b219ad77f8155abf1a287ce2ba60f14998a3a98c0cf14915eabfdacf914a92b27a01769de18fa2d049dbf4c17694@[::]:30303',
  NodeID: '3414c01c19aa75a34f2dbd2f8d0898dc79d6b219ad77f8155abf1a287ce2ba60f14998a3a98c0cf14915eabfdacf914a92b27a01769de18fa2d049dbf4c17694',
  IP: '::',
  DiscPort: 30303,
  TCPPort: 30303,
  Td: '2044952618444',
  ListenAddr: '[::]:30303'
}
```

A **second possibility** is that your local time might be incorrect. An accurate clock is required to participate in the Ethereum network. Check your OS for how to resync your clock (example sudo ntpdate -s time.nist.gov) because even 12 seconds too fast can lead to 0 peers.

Comment: You'd better propose these investigation ways in comment. But as you are new you have to ask a question or answer some first to gain points to be able to comment,.